# html parser python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a website. I am using the HTMLParser module. The problem is i want to parse the first `<a href="">` after the comment: `<!-- /topOfPage -->`, but I don't really know how to do it. So I have found in the documentation that there is an function which is called `handle_comment`, but I haven't  found out how to use it correctly. I have the following:

```
import HTMLParser

class LinkFinder(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Can't use super() - HTMLParser is an old-style class
    HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.in_linktag = False
    self.url_cache = []
def handle_comment(self,data):
    if data == "topOfPage":
        print data
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == "a" and any("href" == t[0] for t in attrs): # found link
        self.in_linktag = True
        self.url_cache.append([dict(attrs)['href']])
def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag == "a" and self.in_linktag: # ignore '<a name=""...'
        self.in_linktag = False
def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.in_linktag:
        self.url_cache[-1].append(data)
TESTDATA = """
< html>
< body>
< div>
 < ul>
    < !-- /topOfPage --> 
< tr >
    < td class="empty-cell-left">&nbsp;</td>
    < td class="image">


    < a  href="http://test" rel="nofollow">
 < ul>
< /div>
< /body>
 < /html>
"""
def main():
lf = LinkFinder()
lf.feed(TESTDATA)
lf.close()
print lf.url_cache
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional variable to indicate that the parser has just come past to the comment, so that you can save the reference from the first link after it.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    self.first_link_after_comment = False
```

Then, when you encounter the comment, the flag must be switched.

```
def handle_comment(self, data):
    if data.strip() == '/topOfPage':
        self.first_link_after_comment = True
```

When you handle an opening tag, you want to be sure to just make it pass by if the parsing has not passed over the comment

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if not self.first_link_after_comment:
        return
    # ...
```

Conversely, when you handle the closing tag, you want to acknowledge that the mission has been accomplished.

```
def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    if tag == 'a' and self.in_linktag: # ignore '<a name=""...'
        self.in_linktag = False
        self.first_link_after_comment = False
```

Finally, when you append data, just make sure that it's not just a string that's empty or contains white space only.

```
def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.in_linktag and data.strip():
        self.url_cache[-1].append(data)
```

And here you are.

```
$ your_script.py
[['http://test']]
```

Answer (score 1):

handle_comment returns **all** of the data between the delimiters.

In this example, the data would actually be " /topOfPage " (note the spaces and /).

You could also do this instead:

```
def handle_comment(self,data):
    if "topOfPage" in data:
        print data
```